# openFileOutput: How to create files outside the /data/data.... path

Tags: java, android

I wonder whether you can help me out with this question. I don't understand how I can access e.g. the "Download" folder or some of my own folder.

I want to create some txt-files and have access to it over USB. I didn't find a topic related to my question cause I don't know where exactly I am searching for.

```
        String string = "hello world!";

        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(string.getBytes());
        fos.close();
```

Thanks for hints :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start by reading [the official documentation on file storage options](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html). Remember that external storage doesn't equate to "removable SD-card". It can just as easily be the 32Gb or whatever memory you have on your Nexus device.

Here's an example of how to get the base folder of the files dir (ie the folder that gets deleted when you uninstall the app, as opposed to the cache dir that still exist even after uninstall):

```
String baseFolder;
// check if external storage is available
if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    baseFolder = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()
}
// revert to using internal storage
else {
    baseFolder = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
}

String string = "hello world!";
File file = new File(basefolder + "test.txt");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

UPDATE: Since you require the file to be accessible via USB and your PCs file manager instead of DDMS or similar you could use the [Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) and pass [Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) as argument (note that I'm not sure if there's an equivalent for the internal storage):

```
String baseFolder;
// check if external storage is available
if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    baseFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
}
// revert to using internal storage (not sure if there's an equivalent to the above)
else {
    baseFolder = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
}

String string = "hello world!";
File file = new File(basefolder + File.separator + "test.txt");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Comment: Okay thats good to know. I will read the doc and try to understand your code.

Comment: I got the following in the LogCat:
06-10 13:19:37.647: E/AndroidRuntime(25405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 13:19:37.647: E/AndroidRuntime(25405): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/de.scuido.hddeasypull/filestest.txt contains a path separator
How it is possible to save to another location with the given baseFolder? I don't understand what kind of path I have to use for that.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Forgot that you used openFileOutput(). Check my updated answer where I create a File and pass that to the FileOutputStream()

Comment: After starting the APP I am not be able to find "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/de.scuido.hddeasypull/files/test.txt" via USB. There is no new folder.

Comment: Odd, ok, three things to try: 1) call file.getParentFile().mkdirs(); to make sure that all folders are created. 2) call fos.flush(); before closing stream 3) change to new File(basefolder + File.separator + "test.txt);

Comment: My fault, the file will be created by the APP but cannot be accessed by USB. I be able to open the file with an file-explorer.

Comment: Yes, or using the Eclipse DDMS file explorer.

Comment: The problem is that I need to get the files via USB and a normal explorer not DDMS.

Comment: Ok, updated my answer. Didn't understand that USB and normal file explorer was a requirement.