# How can I specify a file path using openFileOutput()?

Tags: android, file, storage, android-sdcard, android-context

I've created a program where a user can create an `arrayList`, and then that list is saved into a text file on the storage device. I used this code from https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html :

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to find a way to put this onto external storage. I know what you're thinking: Why not just do it like the way they have posted? Well I don't have an external sdcard in my phone, and I use the internal storage, which is still an sd card (When I go to storage settings it shows user application space and internal sd card storage, there is an external sd card storage- I just don't have an sdcard). I know there is an Environment.get... but that is for external. When I use Context.MODE_PRIVATE, it is storing it in the app's folder, but I need the user to be able to access this file, and copy it onto a computer after.

Answer (score 1):

> Well I don't have an external sdcard in my phone

That is not [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). That is [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

> When I go to storage settings it shows user application space and internal sd card storage

What an Android device reports to the user, and what the Android SDK reports to you, are different. [Internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) are both part of the on-board flash. The only difference is that external storage is something that the user (and other apps) can access, while each app's portion of internal storage is inaccessible to most users.

> I know there is an Environment.get... but that is for external

`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` on `Environment`, and `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context` are for [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). External storage is not [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

> When I use Context.MODE_PRIVATE, it is storing it in the app's folder, but I need the user to be able to access this file, and copy it onto a computer after.

Then use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` on `Environment` if it fits one of those types of public directories. Otherwise, use `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`. Both point to locations on [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), which the user can access (e.g., mount the device as a drive in Windows).

Comment: Alright thanks. After this answer I searched more about the publicDirectory and found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022221/openfileoutput-how-to-create-files-outside-the-data-data-path . I do have a question about it, and was wondering if you could answer it. I'm implementing the if/else (under the answerer's update) to check and set the baseFolder, but under the if statement, it's giving me the error: required: String, found: File. I add a .toString(), but then get an error at outputStream = openFileOutput(file, baseFolder); saying (String, int), found (String string)...